# How do you configure I/O throttles on multiple block devices within one cgroup?

Tags: linux, system-administration, cgroups

I have set up my system to use cgroups through the `cgroup-bin` package, which includes a few nice utilities for mounting and configuring cgroup subsystems. In my `/etc/cgconfig.conf`, I have a block like the following:

```
group limitio {
  blkio {
    blkio.throttle.read_bps_device = "<maj:min> 10485760";
  }
}
```

That works. However, I have multiple devices that I want to throttle I/O to. So, I tried listing them with several different delimiters but nothing seems to work.

Then I thought I would have `cgsnapshot` generate the configuration file for me from a manually configured machine. So I tried the following:

```
echo "<maj2:min2> 10485760" >> /path/to/limitio/blkio.throttle.read_bps_device
```

The manual update works and I see 2 lines in `/path/to/limitio/blkio.throttle.read_bps_device` but the following configuration, generated by `cgsnapshot -s`, does not work.

```
group limitio {
  blkio {
    blkio.throttle.read_bps_device = "<maj1:min1> 10485760
    <maj2:min2> 10485760";
  }
}
```

How do you make this work properly for more than 1 block devices without resorting to just creating separate subgroups?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat the configuration for this namespace, with the new device value:

```
# limits for device 1:1
group limitio {
  blkio {
    blkio.throttle.read_bps_device = "<maj1:min1> 10485760";
  }
}

# limits for device 2:2
group limitio {
  blkio {
    blkio.throttle.read_bps_device = "<maj2:min2> 10485760";
  }
}
```